# Python Dict Key with Multiple Values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm learning about dictionaries, and I know I could do this by creating two more dictionaries, but for brevity's sake, I wanted to make the code a bit more concise than having to create two more dict (granted, in the end, everything I wrote out for this dict would have to be written in the other dicts), so I guess I'm more curious than anything. And I know that I shouldn't be using a for-loop, but I don't know another way, and as far as LPTH sucking, I had to start somewhere.

question 1: How can I get this to cycle through each state/abbrev/city? Would I have to just make multiple dicts, or a series of lists and use those?
question2: Why does this code run the for-loop 11 times?

```
states1 = {
    '1': 'Oregon', 'a': 'OR','population': '1000',
    '2': 'Florida', 'b': 'MI', 'population': '1000',
    '3': 'California', 'c': 'CA', 'population': '1000',
    '4': 'NewYork', 'd': 'NY', 'population': '1000',
    '5': 'Michigan','e': 'MI','population': '1000',
}

for city, pop, in states1.items():
    print "%s has the abbreviation %s and a population of %s" %states1['1'], states1['a'], states1['population'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd have a homgonous datastructure -- e.g. a `list` of `dict`<sup>1</sup>.  Each `dict` would hold the information about a particular state:

```
states1 = [
  {'name': 'Oregon', 'abbrev': 'OR', 'population': 1000},
  {'name': 'Florida', 'abbrev': 'FL', 'population': 1000},
  ...,
]
```

Now your loop looks like this:

```
for state in states1:
    print print "%s has the abbreviation %s and a population of %s" % (state['name'], states['abbrev'], states['population'])
```

The benefit here is hopefully clear.  For any given state, you retrieve the related information the same way (the state's name is always reachable via the `'name'` key).

If you ever need a mapping of state names (e.g. you want to look up a bunch of state's populations by their abbreviation), you can do that pretty easily by creating a dict...

```
abbrev_to_state = {state['abbrev']: state for state in states1}
florida_data = abbrev_to_state['FL']
new_hampshire_data = abbrev_to_state['NH']
...
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>There are other options here too... You could use a custom class, but this also seems like a good candidate for a list of `collections.namedtuple` assuming you aren't planning on mutating the data.</sup>

Comment: That helped a TON mgilbson and I cannot believe I did not think about that, it seems so stupidly simple now!

Answer (score 0):

You could make each value be a list.

I do not understand what exactly you want to achieve, but the easy way would be:

```
states1 = {
1: ["Oregon", "OR", 1000]
2: ["Florida", "FL", 1000]
3: ["Pythonville", "PY", 1000]
4: ["Dictville", "DI", 1000]
}
```

Another thing you could look up is [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), it is one of my favorite data structures for when you want to quickly organize data.

```
from collections import namedtuple

CityInfo = namedtuple("CityInfo", ["Name", "Abbr", "Pop"])

states1 = {
            1: CityInfo("Oregon", "OR", 1000),
            2: CityInfo("Florida", "FL", 1000),
            3: CityInfo("Pythonville", "PY", 1000),
            4: CityInfo("Dictville", "DI", 1000)
            }

for city in states1.values():
    print("{} has the abbreviation {} and a population of {}".format(city.Name, city.Abbr, city.Pop))
```

Comment: FWIW, a dict with sequential integers as keys seems a bit like a waste of memory.  a `list` is usually better in this case :-)

Comment: True, yeah. But I did not want to completely change his code.

Answer (score 0):

When I run it as you recommended me to (below), it spits out

```
Michigan has the abbreviation MI and a population of 1000
Michigan has the abbreviation MI and a population of 1000
Michigan has the abbreviation MI and a population of 1000
```

not sure why it's continually doing that, I would have guessed if it was for some reason to choose a totally random state because it's a dictionary that it would change the state each time, with occasional duplicates.

```
states1 = {
    'state': 'Oregon', 'abbrev': 'OR','population': '10000',
    'state': 'Florida', 'abbrev': 'MI', 'population': '1000',
    'state': 'California', 'abbrev': 'CA', 'population': '1000',
    'state': 'NewYork', 'abbrev': 'NY', 'population': '1000',
    'state': 'Michigan','abbrev': 'MI','population': '1000',
}

for city, pop, in states1.items():
    print "%s has the abbreviation %s and has a population of %s" % (states1['state'], states1['abbrev'], states1['population'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example of how you could structure your data depending on your needs.

```
states1 = {
'Oregon': {'abrv': 'OR','population': '1000'},
'Florida':{ 'abrv': 'MI', 'population': '1000'},
'California':{'abrv': 'CA', 'population': '1000'},
'NewYork':{'abrv': 'NY', 'population': '1000'},
'Michigan':{'abrv': 'MI','population': '1000'}}



for state in states1:
  print "%s has the abbreviation %s and a population of %s" %(state, states1[state]['abrv'], states1[state]['population'])
```

Comment: Thought this looked really perfect in my mind, as did the first suggestion, but both are giving me errors. This one says " File "ex39-test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    print "%s has the abbreviation %s and has a population of %s" % (state, states1[state]['abbrev'], states1[state]['population'])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'"

Comment: Not sure why you're getting that error if your're the exact code. Unhashable dict type would raise if I tried to use a  dictionary as a key.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw the last post, that makes a lot of sense. As far as how this could be useful, I don't know, it was just something I wanted to do, have three values to one key. I'm sure in the future I could take the info from a website or database and have it create pairs, like actors to characters played, but maybe not. It was just something I was annoyed I couldn't figure out on my own.